# Supporting documents for uk visitor visa-original or copies will do?

Tags: visas, uk

UK visitor visa checklist for supporting documents asks to provide original and copy of each document during the appointment.
In regards to letter of invitation ( I will be staying with my sister, who is a British citizen and owns the house she lives in), she was going to email me the invite and send scanned copies of her passport, pay slip, bank statement and title deed. Is an email copy print out and scanned copy printout of her documents acceptable to hand it?

I have read similar questions on this website, but none of them were asked recently.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: If the questions were not asked recently, it means nothing has changed since the last time the rules changed (April 2015).

Answer (score 2):

The [UK Visas & Immigration supporting documents guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) continues to be the operative directive. Her email to you and scanned documents would be acceptable but be sure to include your own financial statements.

> ## [Documents you must provide](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide)
>
> When you apply you’ll need to provide:
>
> - a current passport or other valid travel identification
> - evidence that you can support yourself during your trip, such as bank statements or payslips from the last 6 months
>
> **Read the [full list of supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents) you can provide.**
>
> ### Section 2: other documents you may want to provide – all visitors
>
> This section provides guidance on the types of documents that you may want to provide to help us consider your application against the Immigration Rules.
>
> Previous travel documents/passports, which show previous travel.
>
> Financial documents showing that you have sufficient funds available. These must clearly show that you have access to the funds, such as:
>
> - bank statements
> - building society book
> - proof of earnings such as a letter from employer confirming employment details (start date of employment, salary, role, company contact details)
> - where a third party (who is either in the UK or who will be legally in the UK at the time of your visit) is providing financial support to you e.g. a business, a friend or a relative, documents to show they have sufficient resources to support you in addition to themselves and any dependant family should be provided
>
> Confirmation of legal residence, if you are not a national of the country in which you are applying or your right to reside there is not included in your passport.
>
> Details of employment or studies where you have stated in your application that you are either employed or in full-time studies. This could include:
>
> - a letter from your employer on company headed paper, detailing your role,
> - salary and length of employment
> - a letter from your education provider, on headed paper, confirming your enrolment and leave of absence
>
> If self employed: business registration documents confirming the business owner’s name and the date the business started trading.

Comment: [The supporting documents guide](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) now says that all documents must be originals and not photocopies. Does this mean no scanned copies of any document?