# UK standard visitor visa for family visit

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, yemeni-citizens

A mother (applicant) is looking to come to the UK to visit her own mother (British), siblings (2 brothers, 4 sisters - all British), and two daughters (not British, on spouse visas). Her father is deceased (was British). The applicant is married and currently resides in Saudi Arabia with a residence permit that expires after 1 year (can be renewed) and is a citizen of Yemen. The applicant has her husband, one daughter and two sons, who live with her in Saudi Arabia. She intends to come to the UK for 2 months, primarily because her mother is old and unwell, but she will also see her family members (siblings, daughters). She is unemployed and does not have a bank account.

My question is, how would I provide proof for the following areas:

- You'll leave the UK at the end of your visit.
- Financial documents showing that you have sufficient funds available.

I would appreciate any help as the applicant (my wife's mother) is very eager to come to the UK (she has many years ago in the past, but the procedures have changed a lot since then).

Edit: Her family will support her financially, and she will live at her brother's house (which is where the applicant's mother resides).

Thanks!

Comment: Who is supporting her normally in Saudi Arabia? Also how much time is left on the SA residence permit? Is it feasible to renew the SA residence permit before she applies for the UK Visa?

Comment: Nobody can truly prove that they will leave at the end of a visit. The application for a visa is usually about showing the applicant has a good reason to return to their home country. If the applicant's spouse is not coming with her, that is one example of a good reason to return.

Answer (score 2):

To your points, in this individual’s UK standard visit visa application, she would want to show home ties and her own financial capabilities.

No one can guarantee that she’ll leave at the end of her visit, nor do your financial documents lift her obligation to demonstrate that she qualifies. Sponsorship, in actuality, can raise the bar.

**Home ties:** 
She is married, living in Saudi with her husband and children. She might include, for example, information on her husband’s employment, ages of children and ongoing educational commitments, conditions under which she and her family reside there (e.g., home ownership, rental obligations. In her case, she may need to include the evidence that she is a legal resident, if her right to reside is not included in her Yemeni passport.

**Financial ability**

> Edit: Her family will support her financially, and she will live at her brother's house (which is where the applicant's mother resides).

While she may not have a bank account of her own, the absence of any financial documents (her husband’s bank statements, proof his earnings, etc), may adversely affect her application.

The [UK Visas & Immigration supporting documents guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) is clear:

> **Documents you must provide**
>
> When you apply you’ll need to provide:
>
> - a current passport or other valid travel identification
> - evidence that you can support yourself during your trip, such as bank statements or payslips from the last 6 months
>
> Read the [full list of supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents) you can provide.
>
> **Section 2: other documents you may want to provide – all visitors**
>
> This section provides guidance on the types of documents that you may want to provide to help us consider your application against the Immigration Rules.
>
> Previous travel documents/passports, which show previous travel.
>
> Financial documents showing that you have sufficient funds available. These must clearly show that you have access to the funds, such as:
>
> - bank statements
> - building society book
> - proof of earnings such as a letter from employer confirming employment details (start date of employment, salary, role, company contact details)
> - where a third party (who is either in the UK or who will be legally in the UK at the time of your visit) is providing financial support to you e.g. a business, a friend or a relative, documents to show they have sufficient resources to support you in addition to themselves and any dependant family should be provided
>
> Confirmation of legal residence, if you are not a national of the country in which you are applying or your right to reside there is not included in your passport.

**TSE resources**:

[Here are my ties to my home country. Do you think they are enough? How can I prove them?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72007/here-are-my-ties-to-my-home-country-do-you-think-they-are-enough-how-can-i-pro)

[UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

[What should a sponsor tell the ECO?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69228/what-should-a-sponsor-tell-the-eco/69233#69233)

[Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

[Supporting documents for uk visitor visa-original or copies will do?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96131/supporting-documents-for-uk-visitor-visa-original-or-copies-will-do)